# Memory management when using CFStrings from de AddressBook

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, addressbook, cfstring

I am reading records from the AddressBook using the Apple provided API.

I am still getting my head around memory management and so `CFStrings` are confusing me at the moment.

This is how I am getting the properties:

```
//Get Basic properties
NSString* firstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
NSString* lastName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
NSNumber* record = [NSNumber numberWithInt:ABRecordGetRecordID(person)];

//Build Full Name
NSString* fullName=[self fullNameWith:firstName and:lastName];

//Get Phone number and Label
ABMultiValueRef phone = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
    //Turn identifier into index
CFIndex index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(phone, identifier);
    //Get the value and the label using the index
NSString *value =(NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phone, index);
CFStringRef label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phone, index);
    //Get the localized value of hte label
NSString * localizedLabel = (NSString *)ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(label);
```

After that I use the values, the only thing is that I dont know if I should release them or not.

I would appreciate an answer that also helped me understand memory management better or that points me to the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule of thumb for Core Foundation is that any functions that include `Copy` or `Create` in their name will return an object that you are responsible for releasing. Apple's [Memory Management Guide for Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH) explains this in a bit more detail.

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify, when you do the cast from CFString to NSString do you do [string release] or CFRelease(string)?

Comment: Actually, in this case, they'll behave the exact same because CFString and NSString are "toll-free bridged." I would use whichever one is clearest and most easily understood for your code and whoever may read it.